# Assertj softassertions throwing exception

Tags: assertj

Assertj soft assertion is throwing exception, its only doing the first assertion and its failing after.
any help will be appreciated.

```
    org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertionError: 
    The following assertion failed:
    1) 
    Expected size:<8> but was:<7> in:
    <"seleniu">
    at SpringTest.lambda$stringTest$0(SpringTest.java:15)
        at org.assertj.core.api.AbstractSoftAssertions.throwsBestMultipleAssertionsError(AbstractSoftAssertions.java:198)
        at org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertions.assertAll(SoftAssertions.java:131)
        at org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertions.assertSoftly(SoftAssertions.java:159)
```

public class SpringTest {

```
@Test(dataProvider = "getData")
public void stringTest(String input){

    //Soft assertions.
    assertSoftly(softAssertions -> {
        softAssertions.assertThat(input)
                .hasSize(8)
                .startsWith("se")
                .doesNotContain("api")
                .doesNotContainAnyWhitespaces()
                .containsOnlyOnce("i");
    });

}

@DataProvider
public Object[] getData(){
    return new String[]{
            "seleniu",
            "selenide"
    };
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share some code that demonstrates the actual behavior? And what is your expected behavior?

Comment: thanks for the response, here is the code to see the softassertion behavior, updated with the test code.

Comment: The behavior seems correct as only `hasSize(8)` with the `seleniu` value fails, or am I missing something?

Comment: its only asserting the first one, (with size), its not proceeding with the rest of the checks.

Comment: except for the size all the other assertions succeed, that's why you get only one error reported.

Comment: thanks for the response, appreciate your help.